# I want one character at a time on html page. After completion load next one

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a javascript app.
I have stuck to implementing this.
I am able to load all characters but I want to implement :- load one characters after on completion load next characters.
One characters at a time.

[image]

I want to load one character. After completion load next then again after completion next but one character at a time.
 https://hanziwriter.org/docs.html

```js
var chars = new Array('我','很','爱');

console.log(chars);

for(i=0; i< chars.length; i++){
     console.log(chars[i]);
    writeFunction(chars[i])
}



//c = '我';

function writeFunction(c){

    var writer = HanziWriter.create('character-target-div' , c , {
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        showCharacter: false,
        padding: 5
      });
      writer.quiz({
        onMistake: function(strokeData) {
          console.log('Oh no! you made a mistake on stroke ' + strokeData.strokeNum);
          console.log("You've made " + strokeData.mistakesOnStroke + " mistakes on this stroke so far");
          console.log("You've made " + strokeData.totalMistakes + " total mistakes on this quiz");
          console.log("There are " + strokeData.strokesRemaining + " strokes remaining in this character");
        },
        onCorrectStroke: function(strokeData) {
          console.log('Yes!!! You got stroke ' + strokeData.strokeNum + ' correct!');
          console.log('You made ' + strokeData.mistakesOnStroke + ' mistakes on this stroke');
          console.log("You've made " + strokeData.totalMistakes + ' total mistakes on this quiz');
          console.log('There are ' + strokeData.strokesRemaining + ' strokes remaining in this character');
        },
        onComplete: function(summaryData) {
          console.log('You did it! You finished drawing ' + summaryData.character);
          console.log('You made ' + summaryData.totalMistakes + ' total mistakes on this quiz');

          flagComplete = true;

        }
      });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hanzi-writer@2.2/dist/hanzi-writer.min.js"></script>

<div id="character-target-div"></div>
```

Comment: So what part of that are you stuck on? "I want to do X" is not the kind of question [for asking on Stackoverflow](/help/on-topic), if you want to do X, figure out how you can turn that into a number of smaller tasks, search the web on how you might do each of those, and once you get stuck on one of those, that's a good time to ask on Stackoverflow. Is there a specific part that you're stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to only continue your loop when the user has completed the character. That means your loop must become asynchronous.

JavaScript offers `async` and `await` for that purpose. The only requirement is that you provide a promise that resolves when the character is completed.

Here is how it could work (untested):

```
(async function() { // <-- add this wrapper
    var chars = new Array('我','很','爱');

    console.log(chars);

    for(i=0; i< chars.length; i++){
         console.log(chars[i]);

        await writeFunction(chars[i]);
    //  ^^^^^    
    }
})(); // execute immediately


//c = '我';


// Make the function async, so it returns a promise
async function writeFunction(c) {
    // Wrap the code inside a Promise constructor callback:
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var writer = HanziWriter.create('character-target-div' , c , {
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            showCharacter: false,
            padding: 5
        });
        writer.quiz({
            onMistake: function(strokeData) {
                console.log('Oh no! you made a mistake on stroke ' + strokeData.strokeNum);
                console.log("You've made " + strokeData.mistakesOnStroke + " mistakes on this stroke so far");
                console.log("You've made " + strokeData.totalMistakes + " total mistakes on this quiz");
                console.log("There are " + strokeData.strokesRemaining + " strokes remaining in this character");
            },
            onCorrectStroke: function(strokeData) {
                console.log('Yes!!! You got stroke ' + strokeData.strokeNum + ' correct!');
                console.log('You made ' + strokeData.mistakesOnStroke + ' mistakes on this stroke');
                console.log("You've made " + strokeData.totalMistakes + ' total mistakes on this quiz');
                console.log('There are ' + strokeData.strokesRemaining + ' strokes remaining in this character');
            },
            onComplete: function(summaryData) {
                console.log('You did it! You finished drawing ' + summaryData.character);
                console.log('You made ' + summaryData.totalMistakes + ' total mistakes on this quiz');
              // call resolve: that does the magic!
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Very nice, but overkill here? I added a counter and 3 lines

Comment: It work as expected. Thank you for this.   Is it possible to remove previous characters from page?

Comment: found the answer.        document.getElementById('character-target-div').innerHTML = "";

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

I cannot test it since I have no idea how to correctly stroke  any of these

You can change

`setTimeout(writeFunction, 1000)`
to
`writeFunction();`

if you do not want a pause

```js
var chars = new Array('我', '很', '爱'),
  cnt = 0;
writeFunction()



//c = '我';

function writeFunction() {
  if (cnt >= chars.length) return
  c = chars[cnt]

  var writer = HanziWriter.create('character-target-div', c, {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    showCharacter: false,
    padding: 5
  });
  writer.quiz({
    onMistake: function(strokeData) {
      console.log('Oh no! you made a mistake on stroke ' + strokeData.strokeNum);
      console.log("You've made " + strokeData.mistakesOnStroke + " mistakes on this stroke so far");
      console.log("You've made " + strokeData.totalMistakes + " total mistakes on this quiz");
      console.log("There are " + strokeData.strokesRemaining + " strokes remaining in this character");
    },
    onCorrectStroke: function(strokeData) {
      console.log('Yes!!! You got stroke ' + strokeData.strokeNum + ' correct!');
      console.log('You made ' + strokeData.mistakesOnStroke + ' mistakes on this stroke');
      console.log("You've made " + strokeData.totalMistakes + ' total mistakes on this quiz');
      console.log('There are ' + strokeData.strokesRemaining + ' strokes remaining in this character');
    },
    onComplete: function(summaryData) {
      console.log('You did it! You finished drawing ' + summaryData.character);
      console.log('You made ' + summaryData.totalMistakes + ' total mistakes on this quiz');

      flagComplete = true;
      cnt++
      setTimeout(writeFunction, 1000)

    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hanzi-writer@2.2/dist/hanzi-writer.min.js"></script>

<div id="character-target-div"></div>
```